# why is math.sin() not working, or converting to degrees

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I have a simple problem. I am trying to use sin() and I am getting answers different
from my calculator
Here is the code:

```
r = math.sin(45)
q = math.degrees(r)
print(r)
print(q)
```

I am obviously getting the numbers of r = 0.8509035245341184 &
q = 48.75318072861148 which is not the same result as my calculator.

Comment: Because you’re using degrees where you should use radians, and the output of sin is not degrees in any unit so you can’t convert them to such with `degrees`

Comment: sorry for the imbecility but trig is not my strong suit (obviously...)
how do I get math.sin(45) into radians so that I can convert to degrees? (or vice versa)

Comment: essentially why is my calculator giving me different answers than my python IDE

Comment: But surely your `45` is in degrees?

Comment: It's `math.sin(radians(45))` - you need to feed radians to sin.

Comment: A full circle is 360°, which is the same as 2π radians. If that is not enough information, i suggest searching the web for "convert degrees to radians".

Comment: If you need to learn trig, [math.se] is the place to ask.

Comment: I have fixed the first variable "r" thank you for the help guys

r = math.sin(math.radians(45))
print(r)

Answer (score 4):

As it was noted here, `math.sin` accepts radians input.

More to it, to reverse from sine value to degrees, you would need to obtain inverse sine, which is `arcsin` and is in radians in `math`, and then obtain degrees from that.

```
r = math.sin(math.radians(45))
q = math.degrees(math.asin(r))
print(r)
print(q)
```

Output:

```
0.7071067811865475
44.99999999999999
```